# How to control a non-neural link controlled jumpjet/jetpack

Tags: physics, bio-mechanics, control

When looking at movies and games, jumpjets/jetpacks are often easy to control. In games its a matter of a keyboard press away and in movies it more or less does exactly what the person asks of it, often without an explanation of how or with the simple explanation of neural link.

I'm working on a story with a jumpjet. For ease of use this jumpjet stabilizes itself in an upright position and the owner only needs to focus on up, down, left, right, forwards backwards, if possible this is analogue so you can go diagonal at any angle of these options. The problem is: when these jetpacks are necessary elaborate electrical systems dont work. Ignoring the difficulty of stabilizing the jumpjet the actual controls are now a lot more difficult. I cant use the magic neural link and say "it just works". I need a solid control mechanism.

Small edit: I'll be using a game/movie jumpjet rather than the miniature vehicles we have in real life.

A compounding problem is that this jumpjet needs to be operated while the hands are occupied (say carrying a child or handling tools or weapons, ignoring again the difficulty if stabilization or fuel usage when thrusters at your chest are mostly blocked). So you cant use two joysticks (which would not be elaborate enough and still work). This leaves me wondering: what kind of system could I use to control this jumpjet?

The best answer would require the least thought of the user, while hindering the user as little as possible while controlling his/her jumpjet.

Comment: How about an ejection seat? That's the solution used by pretty much every naturally unstable fly by wire manned aircraft.

Comment: So, to clarify your restrictions: No elaborate electrical systems,  no magic neural link, and it must be able to be competently piloted while the wearer's hands are occupied?

Comment: @Halfthawed yes, some computerized assists is allowed but in the end the user is in full control of the direction and power (if the power isnt set). As for user19something's suggestion: ejection seats dont seem to have any control aside from "up/down out of the aircraft" and then just drift down using parachutes.

Comment: @Demigan My point with the ejection seat is that the way most unstable fly-by-wire aircraft handle the problem of control failure is to eject the pilot in the event of a failure, so that you don't need to handle the problem of manual reversion. Or in other words, the manual reversion for your platform could consist of release the parachute.

Comment: @user1937198 the question isnt about control failure or even aircraft for that matter. Its about controlling a jumpjet/jetpack without using your hands.

Comment: @Demigan Then I completely misinterpreted your question. How much control does the user need? Are we talking dog fighting, transport or something else? Could you alternate the command of the to jetpack to get into a position and use of hands in a position? Could you potentially mount tools/weapons in a way that frees up the hands like the apaches gunships eye tracking system?

Comment: @user1937198 I find it hard to balance the preciseness of the question with the shortness that will prevent too much segways and misinterpretations. Is used jumpjet/jetpack alongside mentions of movies and games on purpose to guide readers. A jumpjet is pure fiction and often a wearable unrestricting suit or backpack sized item that is active for mere seconds. Its use for urban or mountainous terrain crossings. That is also why the controls are simple: up, down, forwards, backwards, left and right. They will not be miniature aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

### GPS Canned Flight Paths and Hot Keys

Both aircraft and drone craft use flight plans that are pre-built by the pilot and operator. These often include :

- your planned destination (aviation),
- emergency alternate destinations (aviation),
- execute a pre-loaded flight plan (aviation + drones) hitting certain lat/lon/alt GPS waypoints
- home (drones),
- relative directions : 10 m up/down/left/right/fwd/back,
- relative paths : figure-8, orbit, or Immelman around the point (aviation+drone),
- land (aviation+drones).

With a single key-press, then, an operator can execute some pretty sophisticated paths.

### Verbal Commands

Speech-to-text is getting much better. Especially among remotes, verbal command can be used to execute canned actions with varying degrees of complexity.

### Adjustable Stick Meaning + Sensitivity

If absolutely hands-free, the flight can be controlled by shifts in weight. With no input, the device either maintains present position, or maintains the present flight path.

Stick inputs can be interpreted as either :

- absolute changes to the current position (if hovering),
- relative changes to the current flight vector (if already underway),
- linear deviations from the current flight vector (side-shift up/down/left/right, but keep same heading).

Sensitivity can also be adjusted, so that accidentally bumping the stick does not widely throw the vehicle. Sensitivity can scale by;

- how far the deflection is made (so that you can get full authority at the extremes, and fine adjustment near neutral)
- time deflected (starting with a small change, and giving more authority the longer its held)
- speed of deflection (damp out quick impulses or, alternatively, give full authority to panic inputs)
- manual (user chooses sensitivity).

Answer (score 1):

One of the original devices this meme comes from, the Hiller Flying Platform, as well as a jet-powered successor, were controlled much like a Segway or "hoverboard" (a Segway without the handle): by weight shift alone.  Both the flying platform (a ducted fan thrust-hover machine) and the jet version (which use a pair of small turbofan engines) did, of course, need a throttle to control vertical movement -- but these devices preceded computer controls (as used in modern drones) by decades.

Either one could be flown with a second, virtually helpless person aboard; the passenger would curl up in the bottom of the cockpit space (which was basically a large garbage can with a door and very simple control panel) and the operator would fly normally, merely having to compensate for the magnitude and position of the passenger's weight.

Comment: Interesting. Although I just looked it up and the video showed the soldier putting away his things, grabbing the railing and using that to steer rather than his weight. This despite the two sites I visited saying it did use weight. This would be wrong as the soldier would have flown everywhere during his actions if purely his weight steered. I'm also at a loss how the person using a jumpjet/jetpack would use thrust. I edited the question to be a bit more clear about the size and shape I had in mind for jumpjets/jetpacks.

Comment: The railing serves to steady the pilot's center of mass over the machine's center of thrust.  How steady can you stand on a moving surface, vs. standing while holding a railing?

Answer (score 0):

Some real-world jetpacks can be controlled by leaning in the right direction. 'Hoverboard' type devices can be handled similarly. A similar hands-free control - possibly with a foot accelerator etc  would not be difficult.   Suggest you Google how real-world engineers have solved the problem.

Comment: I did a quick search but I found a mountain of information about the materials, thrust, fuel and velocities of these things and a single mention of a joystick control. Could you give some more detail to your controls or offer links?